# Default size setting in gmail

Tags: gmail

Copied from your suggestions:

Under "Mail Settings" on the "General" tab, you should see something like this:

default font selector

This allows you to define whether your default text is bold, Italicized, which font is used*, font size (Small, Normal, Large, Huge), font color, and remove existing formatting.

I don't see DEFAULT FONT SELECTOR in my settings. Where could it be?

Comment: Have you been able to configure it per my instructions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable GMail Labs and then go to Labs tab in Settings and enable Default Text Styling feature.